# Bug: when displaying reputation, if AJAX answer takes too much time to come

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here's a small bug I've just faced: if you display someone's reputation, and you click on the small triangle to display the reputation, there's an AJAX call that is made.

Usually the answer is so fast that there's no problem.

But when the answer takes too much time, you have the time to click once again on the triangle, and to re-click for the third time (follow me?) so that there's another AJAX call that is made.

The result is that when both AJAX answers come, they're both appended, see here:

[image: Small bug]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with how we were disabling additional fetches for a single day.

A fix will be pushed in the next build (after rev 2012.2.10.1004*).

<sub>* see footer's right for build number</sub>